# I keep getting "undefined" when using the function $_GET in PHP, why is this?

Tags: php, get, undefined

I continue to get `undefined` printed out when I use `print($_GET['user_username']);` from the previous page. The URL of the page is `page.php?user_username=Pete`. Why is this happening?

Comment: try using isset() function to check if the data is not coming null.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: This is all the code: `<?php print($_GET['user_username']); ?>`

Comment: is that code in page.php? I'm confused by "previous page"

Comment: `undefined` sounds more like a javascript variable than a php message. Is that the complete message or is it `Notice: Undefined index: user_username in /xxx/xxx/xxx/page.php on line xx`?

Comment: I have printed $_GET so undefined is in the text where the value should be but I am passing it with ajax, that was a good observation lol

Answer (score 0):

[$_GET manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) says

> An associative array of variables
>   passed to the current script via the
>   URL parameters.

First be sure that element exists

```
<?php
  echo !isset($_GET["user_username"]) ? "undefined" : $_GET["user_username"];
?>
```

Or try `var_dump` against `$_GET` array to see if element with `user_username` key exists.

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Is your request like this one?

**http://www.mydomain.com/something.php?user_username=something**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

You will get all the elements passed using get in array format. Then you can check it.. It also helps better in debugging many times.